Values are returning null objects despite existing in mysql db
I am perplexed as to why my values are returning as object types instead of number/int types even though they are defined as such, in addition, there are values existing in the table but upon sequelizing the results, they return as null objects!
Below is a masked version of my sequelize query in node/express js:
const queryResult = await sequelize.query(
  `SELECT tbl1.identifier, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT tbl1.item_id) AS item_count,
          tbl2.assigned_items, 
          tbl3.current_items, 
          tbl3.total_required_items,
          tbl3.expected_items_assigned, 
          tbl3.items_required
   FROM data_table_1 tbl1
   LEFT JOIN data_table_3 tbl3 ON tbl1.identifier = tbl3.identifier
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT identifier, COUNT(*) AS assigned_items
       FROM data_table_2
       GROUP BY identifier
   ) tbl2 ON tbl1.identifier = tbl2.identifier
   WHERE tbl1.identifier = "${someIdentifier}"
   GROUP BY tbl1.identifier;`,
  { type: QueryTypes.SELECT, logging: console.log, raw: true }
);

const {
  identifier,
  total_required_items,
  current_items,
  expected_items_assigned,
  assigned_items,
  item_count,
  items_required,
} = queryResult[0] || {};

Output:
console.log(queryResult);

[
  {
    identifier: 'abc123',
    item_count: 12,
    assigned_items: 2,
    current_items: null,
    total_required_items: null,
    expected_items_assigned: null,
    items_required: null
  }
]

Why are the values returning as null objects ? The same query works in MySQL but it fails during sequelize and i am unsure if it even truly executed the check below even though the results looked good to me.
const canProceed=
  (total_required_items== current_items && item_count> items_required) ||
  total_required_items> current_items||
  identifier== null ||
  identifier== "";


Where are maskedIdentifier, requiredItemsTotal, etc coming from? Those keys don't exist in queryResult[0]

a left join implies that if there are no corresponding valie it sets a NULL, so you need to check if there are no tbl3.identifier for tblq.identifier

@mykaf updated it, i made a mistake

@nbk The query itself doesn't seem to be the problem, since logging queryResult returns the expected values.

@nbk but how is it possible that the same sequelize statement works if i run the raw command in MySQL?

@solace, all set now? Except add a comma after identifier when you are setting your values.

maybie it is only the classics that you are connected to a different sql server

@nbk checked and it isnt, also it manages to extract the staff_id and item_count

Just to be clear @solace, are you saying that you're logging the SQL query, copying the query from the logs, pasting that into MySQL without modification, and it works, but it doesn't work here?

Per @solace's output console.log(queryResult);, the query itself seems like it worked as expected?
